# How to groupby using specific condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
pickup_to_drop_location_km  food_item_quantity
23  4.067   2
24  4.067   1
25  4.067   1
26  7.081   1
27  7.081   1
...     ...     ...
595613  7.834   1
595675  6.199   1
595699  6.324   1
595700  6.324   1
595705  7.500   1
```

If i do simple groupby sum (as standard way)
`df.groupby('pickup_to_drop_location_km').sum()`

i will get:

```
pickup_to_drop_location_km food_item_quantity
0.058     1
0.123     3
0.126     2
0.177     1
0.180     1
         ..
17.046    2
20.561    1
20.915    1
23.201    2
25.244    1
```

But I want to provide a condition such as result would be food_item_quantity should be **max 2** after summing up. For example: if we have dataframe as:

```
pickup_to_drop_location_km  food_item_quantity
23  12.067   2
24  12.067   1
25  12.067   1
26  12.067   1
26  9.381    1
27  9.381    1
```

Result should be like this:

```
pickup_to_drop_location_km  food_item_quantity
23  12.067   2
24  12.067   2
25  12.067   1
26  9.381    2
```

I hope, i am making it clear. food_item_quantity column cannot be more than 2.
Sorry i am only a beginner.!
Anyhelp?!

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understand the question correctly

```
import numpy as np
df2 = df.groupby('pickup_to_drop_location_km').sum()
df2['food_item_quantity'] = np.minimum(df2['food_item_quantity'],2)
```

or without numpy and somewhat more Panda-esque

```
df2 = df.groupby('pickup_to_drop_location_km').sum()
df2[df2['food_item_quantity']>2] = 2
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this. This solution is only is converting greater than 2 values to 2. I was looking for more like groupby summing `'food_item_quantity'` to 2 and if there is any greater value than 2 then making separate row for extra row. I have mentioned it in question description! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clunky but works. First we define a function that "chunks up" a number (say 5) into a list of max allowed numbers and left-over (5->[2,2,1])

```
def chunk_up(n, chunk_size):
    left_over = n%chunk_size
    n_full_groups = n//chunk_size
    chunks = [chunk_size]*n_full_groups 
    if left_over > 0:
        chunks += [left_over]
    return chunks

chunk_up(5,2)
```

prints `[2, 2, 1]`

now we apply this function to summed-up `food_item_quantity` and explode

```
df2 = df.groupby('pickup_to_drop_location_km').sum()
df2['food_item_quantity'] = df2['food_item_quantity'].apply(lambda q: chunk_up(q,2))
df3 = df2.explode('food_item_quantity')
df3
```

prints

```
food_item_quantity pickup_to_drop_location_km   
9.381                 2
12.067                2
12.067                2
12.067                1
```